# Custom CPTPlotDataSource not being called when self was

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot

If implementing CPTPlotDataSource on the MasterViewController object (the only UIViewController in a very simple application which draws a chart) then setting the dataSource on CPTScatterPlot with

```
line.dataSource = self
```

My application works exactly as expected but if I create a small class and make it extend CPTPlotDataSource then set the data source with

```
line.dataSource = NewImplementation()
```

Then neither

```
func numberOfRecordsForPlot(plot: CPTPlot!) -> UInt 
func doubleForPlot(plot: CPTPlot!, field: UInt, recordIndex: UInt) -> Double
```

The only two functions that exist within it ever get called.

Comment: I'm guessing that dataSource property is weak? If that's the case it's deallocated after this assignment :)

Comment: Change this comment to an answer and I will mark it as correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataSource is weak and it's getting deallocated after assignment